# Sumar nodos de un arbol. Prolog

Tags: prolog, árboles, árboles-binarios

Buenos días, soy principiante en Prolog y estoy estudiando tratamiento de listas y árboles.
Una duda que tengo es cómo puedo sumar los nodos de un árbol en principio binario. Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los árboles se representan como una lista de la siguiente manera:

```
[[[[],1,[]],5,[[],4,[]]],7,[[],6,[]]]
```

Usando un predicado como pej sumanodos(tree,S) debe devolver la suma de los nodos pej

```
?-sumanodos( [[[[],1,[]],5,[[],4,[]]],7,[[],6,[]]],S)
S=23
```

Sólo puedo usar los siguientes constructores y selectores de tipo abstracto:

```
nil([]).
leftnode([LN,_,_],LN)
root([_,RT,_],RT)
rightnode([_,_,RN],RN)
tree(RT,LN,RN,[LN,RT,RN])
```

Me interesa sobre todo la explicación, muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 1):

La suma de un árbol vacío es 0:

```
sumanodos([],0).
```

En el caso general, se obtienen recursivamente la suma de la rama izquierda y la suma de la rama derecha, y se devuelve la suma de la raíz con ambas ramas:

```
sumanodos([L,N,R],S) :-
    sumanodos(L,Sl),
    sumanodos(R,Sr),
    S is N+Sl+Sr.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tu solución es la que estaba buscando.

Comment: Si además de la suma quisiera encontrar el nodo con valor máximo del árbol, ¿cómo guardo el contador de ese máximo y voy comparando con otros nodos mientras recorro el árbol?

Answer (score 0):

No trabajo en Prolog pero voy a intentar echarte una mano. Para recorrer los nodos de un arbol lo tienes que hacer de manera recursiva. Tienes tres maneras de recorrerlo, pre-orden, in-orden y post-orden, si sólo te interesa recorrer el árbol sin importarte el orden en el que lo recorras puedes utilizar cualquiera de los 3 métodos. Te dejo una web donde hace los 3 recorridos, sólo tendrás que ir incrementando una variable cada vez que pases por un nodo. http://www.solveet.com/exercises/Recorridos-pre-in-post-orden/91/solution-636

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu enlace me ha servido para aclarar conceptos en los que tenía dudas!